# ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification - PL/SQL - Oracle Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to write this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ManageCall
AFTER INSERT 
ON STATE_CHANGE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (ChangeType='C')
DECLARE
x_coord NUMBER;
y_coord NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT X, Y INTO x_coord, y_coord
    FROM TELEPHONE
    WHERE PHONENO = :NEW.PHONENO;
END;
```

that refers to these tables:

```
TELEPHONE
PHONENO (CHAR) 
X (NUMBER)
Y (NUMBER)
PHONESTATE (CHAR)

STATE_CHANGE
CHANGEID (NUMBER)
TIMESTAMP (DATE)
PHONENO (CHAR)
X (NUMBER)
Y (NUMBER)
CHANGETYPE (CHAR)
```

I think to have use :NEW in the right way but I obtain this message:

```
ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification
```

Can someone explain me where I do a mistake.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `:NEW` and `:OLD` everytime you are refering to the columns that are inserted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ManageCall
    AFTER INSERT 
    ON STATE_CHANGE
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    x_coord NUMBER;
    y_coord NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    IF :NEW.ChangeType='C' THEN
        SELECT X, Y INTO x_coord, y_coord
        FROM TELEPHONE t
        WHERE t.PHONENO = :NEW.PHONENO;
    END IF;
    END;
```

When you are using the `WHEN`-clause, you can't use NEW as a bind variable as stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) (search for 'WHEN clause'):

> The NEW and OLD keywords, when specified in the WHEN clause, are not considered bind variables, so are not preceded by a colon (:). However, you must precede NEW and OLD with a colon in all references other than the WHEN clause.

So the following should work as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ManageCall
    AFTER INSERT 
    ON STATE_CHANGE
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.ChangeType='C')
    DECLARE
    x_coord NUMBER;
    y_coord NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT X, Y INTO x_coord, y_coord
        FROM TELEPHONE
        WHERE PHONENO = :NEW.PHONENO;
    END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. But just another question I haven't understand because I can use .NEW in the WHEN (before DECLARE). Can you explain that? Thank you very much you are been very useful