# ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification in pl/sql don't know what is wrong

Tags: oracle, plsql, eventtrigger

i was designing the trigger on update minimum salary in jobs table with the use of pl/sql but it is showing error: ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_MIN_SALARY
    BEFORE UPDATE OF MIN_SALARY ON JOBS
    FOR EACH ROW WHEN (JOB_ID<>'AD_PRES')
    DECLARE 
    V_CURRENT_MIN_SAL JOBS.MIN_SALARY%TYPE := :OLD.MIN_SALARY;
    BEGIN
    IF (V_CURRENT_MIN_SAL > :NEW.MIN_SALARY) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Minimum salary of the job should not be less than current 
    minimum salary');
    END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: sorry i am really bad at posting my code on this platform

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification - PL/SQL - Oracle Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246567/ora-04076-invalid-new-or-old-specification-pl-sql-oracle-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

It is the `WHEN` clause, which expects pseudorecord - but doesn't allow colon sign with it (it is required in trigger body, though):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_UPDATE_MIN_SALARY
  2      BEFORE UPDATE OF MIN_SALARY ON JOBS
  3      FOR EACH ROW
  4      WHEN (NEW.JOB_ID<>'AD_PRES')              --> here
  5  DECLARE
  6      V_CURRENT_MIN_SAL JOBS.MIN_SALARY%TYPE := :OLD.MIN_SALARY;
  7  BEGIN
  8      IF (V_CURRENT_MIN_SAL > :NEW.MIN_SALARY) THEN
  9          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
 10            (-20000,
 11             'Minimum salary of the job should not be less than current minimum salary');
 12      END IF;
 13  END;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you i was stuck in that colon sign in when clause in trigger name as i was not aware  that there is no need of colon in when clause while using OLD or NEW KEYWORDS . my error has solved

Comment: You're welcome. Also, note that you don't need a local variable - you can directly compare :NEW to :OLD value.